# Sum datetime durations between start and end

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, datediff

I have a table that's tracking an integer status variable with start and end datetime columns. Another program updates the table when the status variable that it's monitoring changes. It sets the end_timestamp of the last entry to the current time, and inserts a new status row with the current time as the start_timestamp. A consequence of this is that the currently elapsing status duration has an end_timestamp of Null.

Here's how it looks:

[image: Here's how it looks.]

I'm trying to find the best way to query for the duration of each status, in seconds, between a given start and end datetime. Summing the status durations that fall cleanly within the provided endpoints is trivial, but I'm unsure of the best way to handle edges. I've done this outside of the DB before, by finding the latest-start and earliest-end, getting the difference, and incrementing sums.

Here is my current query for summing durations, including the currently elapsing one:

```
SELECT status, sum(datediff(S, start_timestamp, ISNULL([end_timestamp], GETDATE()))) as duration
FROM [status_table]
WHERE start_timestamp >= @start AND
(end_timestamp <= @end OR end_timestamp is Null)
GROUP BY status;
```

Sample result:

[image: Sample result.]

Visual reference:

[image: Visual reference]

Comment: Two periods overlap if one starts before the other ends AND it ends after the other starts.  `start < @end AND (end IS NULL OR end > @start) `

Comment: You should also probably Not be using `GETDATE()`, instead it looks like you should be using `ISNULL(end, @end)`

Comment: @MatBailie Great point, and I can just pass the current timestamp as the endpoint in my query when I need up-to the elapsing status. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add a case statement to your SUM, and make sure your where checks that the start and end date falls BETWEEN

```
select  [status],
        sum(datediff(
            second, 
            case when start_timestamp < @start then @start else start_timestamp end, 
            case when end_timestamp is null or end_timestamp > @end then @end else end_timestamp end
            )
        ) as duration
from    status_table
where   (@start <= isnull(end_timestamp,@end))
and     (end_timestamp IS NULL or @end  >= end_timestamp)
group by [status]
```

**update**

to try and keep the query sargable

```
select      [status],
            sum(datediff(second, startdt, enddt)) as duration
from        (
                select      [status],   
                            case when start_timestamp < @start then @start else start_timestamp end as startdt,
                            case when end_timestamp is null or end_timestamp > @end then @end else end_timestamp end as enddt
                from        status_table
                where       (start_timestamp < @end)
                and         (end_timestamp is null or end_timestamp > @start)
) t
group by    [status]
```

Comment: Your where clause can be simplified. If you have `@a <= X OR @a BETWEEN X AND Y` then you actually just have `@a <= Y`

Comment: @MatBailie make sense.. let me see about the end AND as well

Comment: You also copy the OP's use of `GETDATE()`, but by the OP's own description, the proxied end should really just be `@end`

Comment: @MatBailie was correct, with those few changes I got OPs query working as expected. Thanks all!